# [Android]I want to make many buttons with ONE OnClick method

Tags: android, button, android-activity, view

everyone.

I'm trying to write a java code for my android project.

I made an additional activity. Its background is partially translucent, and upon it, there are several buttons. Each button should do similar functions except only one button for exit.

That is,

1. buttons are 10.
2. Button No. 1 ~ 9 are for same function. The function is to gather a string, precedently allocated for each button(e.g. button 1 = "You should be married tomorrow, or be shot!" button 2 = "What? Damn it!") and retriece the message on a message stack(I located it elsewhere). So, if I press button 1, my app would gather the message "You should be married tomorrow, or be shot!" and put it on the message stack. then I press button 2, so my app would gather the message "What? Damn it!" and put the message over the message 1. And so on. So, function for each button is the same.
3. Only one exceptional button is here: exit(). When I press it, the activity calls finish() and I can return to the main activity.

   so, I wrote the code as below:

   ```
   public class PADactivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

       ScrollView BtnPadScrl;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           setContentView(R.layout.virtualpad_activity);
           BtnPadScrl = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.BtnPadScrl);
           BtnPadScrl.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
           BtnPadScrl.setScrollBarDefaultDelayBeforeFade(1500);

         }

     // Warning Message Buttons. 1~9.
     Button btnwrn01 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.wrnbtn01);
     btnwrn01.setOnClickListener(this);
     Button btnwrn02 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.wrnbtn02);
     btnwrn02.setOnClickListener(this);
     Button btnwrn03 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.wrnbtn03);
     btnwrn03.setOnClickListener(this);
     ...
     Button btnwrn09 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.wrnbtn09);
     btnwrn09.setOnClickListener(this);
     // Activity Killer. 1.
     Button killpadnow = (Button)findViewById(R.id.QuitPad);
     killpadnow.setOnClickListener(this);

     @Override
     public void onClick (View v) {
         if (v.getId() == R.id.QuitPad) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Closing Virtual Pad!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             finish();
         }
         else if (v.getId() != R.id.QuitPad) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Still It is a dummy!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         }

    }
   ```

As above, I wrote the code, and when I call the activity, the app was immediately crashed.
Please help me. I will appreciate your advices.

Comment: what is your log cat

Comment: It was too long..I could just extract partly.

Comment: 09-15 10:15:15.722    3208-3212/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 2052K, 39% free 5760K/9372K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 14ms
09-15 10:15:20.152  29439-29439/? V/TaskCloserActivity﹕ TaskCloserActivity resetList mRunningItems.clear
09-15 10:15:20.152  29439-29439/? V/TaskCloserActivity﹕ TaskCloserActivity resetList runningAppsCount : 0
09-15 10:15:20.152  29439-29439/? D/ProgramMonitor﹕ Active Applications count = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your virtualpad_activity layout please add the following for every button

```
  android:onCLick="onClick"
```

Remove @override notation for onClick method and also remove button.setOnClickListener for every button.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but then is there no way to measure many buttons with only one class/method?

Comment: That is the way!! "onClick" is the method name which is called when you click that button. So if you want 10 buttons to use the same method you just have to mention

        android:onClick="onClick"

in all the 10 button tags

Comment: ?!!!! Wow! I just misunderstood, but now I know what you say. I seldom thought on that way before. I'm gonna modify my code right away.Thank you!!!  :-)

Comment: Please up vote the answer if you found it useful. It would be helpful for others too !!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing if and elseif, try if and else:

```
public void onClick (View v) {
      if (v.getId() == R.id.QuitPad) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Closing Virtual Pad!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          finish();
      }
      else  {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Still It is a dummy!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      }

 }
```